# DQL error: DM_QUERY2_E_REPEAT_TYPE_JOIN

Tags: sql, dql, documentum

this is my dql query

```
select 
a.object_name, 
a.r_object_id, 
COUNT(b.r_object_id) as leaf, 
a.r_folder_path 
from dm_folder a left join dm_folder b 
on any b.i_folder_id = a.r_object_id 
where any a.r_folder_path is not null 
AND any a.i_folder_id = '0b01e0f38000e703' 
group by a.object_name, a.r_object_id, a.r_folder_path
```

but i got the error

> [DM_QUERY2_E_REPEAT_TYPE_JOIN]error: "Your query is selecting
>   repeating attributes and joining types."

i tried this one

```
select 
a.object_name, 
a.r_object_id, 
COUNT(b.r_object_id) as leaf, 
a.r_folder_path 
from dm_folder a left join dm_folder b 
on b.i_folder_id = a.r_object_id 
where any a.r_folder_path is not null 
AND a.i_folder_id = '0b01e0f38000e703' 
group by a.object_name, a.r_object_id, a.r_folder_path enable (row_based)
```

but when i used enable (row_based) its not showing the rows with `COUNT(b.r_object_id)` equal to 0...

what can i do?

tnx a lot

Comment: you actually wanna show all folders with their path and number of first level children (only folders)?

Comment: @Miki
yes, i want to show the path of the folder and the number of first level folders children

Comment: your second query shows results when I run it on my environment. Are you using wrong ID 'AND a.i_folder_id = '0b01e0f38000e703' '

Comment: you can drop <a.r_folder_path is not null > part since every folder must have this property

Comment: actually i used folder(id('...')) and now i dont need the path so the problem solved.